# Multiple Explosives

Tags: terraria

If I place multiple explosive blocks next to each other and detonate them all at once, do they each contribute damage to a boss?

I am afraid the answer is no based on the fact that several dart traps, if activated together, will not each damage a creature.  I.e. you have to stagger the activation of each.  So I wonder if the same applies to explosives.

Answer (score 2):

The same does not apply to explosives.<-- original response

please disregard the original response, as i did not completely understood what you asked. I for some reason thought you ment explosives in general what it seems you actually ment was tnt combined with wires.

well to answer the question yes the damage will not combine, entirely. here are a couple videos i found showing completely what you have asked one tested on the wall of the flesh the other a test on himself. hopefully this helps sorry for the bad response originally.

Comment: Could you provide some evidence?

Comment: I will find a video or provide one if you have the patience.

Comment: No worries.  The more substantial your answer, the more votes you get.  Welcome to the site!

Comment: thank you, im very interested in this site never seen anything like it

Comment: It can take some time to get used to.  When you get 20 rep, come by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) and we will be glad to help you out!